# Concatenate dichotome columns to semicolon-separated column

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have data frame containing the results of a multiple choice question. Each item has either 0 (not mentioned) or 1 (mentioned). The columns are named like this:

`F1.2_1, F1.2_2, F1.2_3, F1.2_4, F1.2_5, F1.2_99`
 etc.

I would like to concatenate these values like this: The new column should be a semicolon-separated string of the selected items. So if a row has a 1 in F1.2_1, F1.2_4 and F1.2_5 it should be: `1;4;5`

The last digit(s) of the dichotome columns are the item codes to be used in the string.

Any idea how this could be achieved with R (and data.table)? Thanks for any help!

*edit*:

Here is a example DF with the desired result:

```
structure(list(F1.2_1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), F1.2_2 = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), F1.2_3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), F1.2_4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), F1.2_5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), F1.2_99 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), desired_result = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("1;2;3", "1;3;4", "2", "99"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("F1.2_1", 
"F1.2_2", "F1.2_3", "F1.2_4", "F1.2_5", "F1.2_99", "desired_result"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))




  F1.2_1 F1.2_2 F1.2_3 F1.2_4 F1.2_5 F1.2_99 desired_result
1      0      1      0      0      0       0              2
2      1      0      1      1      0       0          1;3;4
3      0      0      0      0      0       1             99
4      1      1      1      0      0       0          1;2;3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206415/concatenate-dichotome-columns-to-semicolon-separated-column#comment73485380_43206670), the OP asked how to deal with more multiple choice questions.

The approach below will be able to handle an arbitrary number of questions and choices for each question. It uses `melt()` and `dcast()` from the `data.table` package.

## Sample input data

Let's assume the input data.frame `DT` for the extended case contains two questions, one with 6 choices and the other with 4 choices:

```
DT
#   F1.2_1 F1.2_2 F1.2_3 F1.2_4 F1.2_5 F1.2_99 F2.7_1 F2.7_2 F2.7_3 F2.7_11
#1:      0      1      0      0      0       0      0      1      1       0
#2:      1      0      1      1      0       0      1      1      1       1
#3:      0      0      0      0      0       1      1      0      1       0
#4:      1      1      1      0      0       0      1      0      1       1
```

## Code

```
library(data.table)

# coerce to data.table and add row number for later join
setDT(DT)[, rn := .I]

# reshape from wide to long format
molten <- melt(DT, id.vars = "rn")

# alternatively, the measure cols can be specified (in case of other id vars)
# molten <- melt(DT, measure.vars = patterns("^F"))

# split question id and choice id
molten[, c("question_id", "choice_id") := tstrsplit(variable, "_")]

# reshape only selected choices from long to wide format,
# thereby pasting together the ids of the selected choices for each question
result <- dcast(molten[value == 1], rn ~ question_id, paste, collapse = ";", 
                fill = NA, value.var = "choice_id")

# final join for demonstration only, remove row number as no longer needed
DT[result, on = "rn"][, rn := NULL][]
#   F1.2_1 F1.2_2 F1.2_3 F1.2_4 F1.2_5 F1.2_99 F2.7_1 F2.7_2 F2.7_3 F2.7_11  F1.2     F2.7
#1:      0      1      0      0      0       0      0      1      1       0     2      2;3
#2:      1      0      1      1      0       0      1      1      1       1 1;3;4 1;2;3;11
#3:      0      0      0      0      0       1      1      0      1       0    99      1;3
#4:      1      1      1      0      0       0      1      0      1       1 1;2;3   1;3;11
```

For each question, the final result shows which choices were selected in each row.

## Reproducible data

The sample data can be created with

```
DT <- structure(list(F1.2_1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), F1.2_2 = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L), F1.2_3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), F1.2_4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), F1.2_5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), F1.2_99 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), F2.7_1 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), F2.7_2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), F2.7_3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), F2.7_11 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("F1.2_1", "F1.2_2", 
"F1.2_3", "F1.2_4", "F1.2_5", "F1.2_99", "F2.7_1", "F2.7_2", 
"F2.7_3", "F2.7_11"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
 j1 <- do.call(paste, c(as.integer(sub(".*_", "", 
              names(DF)[-7]))[col(DF[-7])]*DF[-7], sep=";"))

 DF$newCol <- gsub("^;+|;+$", "", gsub(";*0;|0$|^0", ";", j1))
 DF$newCol
 #[1] "2"     "1;3;4" "99"    "1;2;3"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works well with the small example - however, in my real data, there are more columns and different multiple choice questions. For example, another one is `F2.7_1`, `F2.7_2`, `F2.7_3`, `F2.7_4` ... and some are just other questions. Any idea how this could be incorporated?

Comment: @Mario  In my first approach, I used column numbers, but when you showed that it is the last part of the column names that is needed, I changed it.  Not sure how you want it to be incorporated

Comment: I thought of something like this in `data.table`: `newCol = ifelse(F1.2_1==1,1,ifelse(F1.2_2,2,ifelse(F1.2_3,3,ifelse(F1.2_4,4,ifelse(F1.2_5,5,ifelse(F1.2_6,6,ifelse(F1.2_7,7,ifelse(F1.2_8,8,ifelse(F1.2_9,9,ifelse(F1.2_99,99,NA))))))))))`- so it is hard coded, but this code only makes one character instead of a ;-separated. Could this somehow be pasted together rowwise

Comment: @Mario That will be inefficient.  The option that I provided will be very fast